# How can I convert wav to wma programmatically in C++?

Tags: c++

How can I convert wav to wma programmatically in C++?

Comment: I like to see you do this _non_ programatically in C++ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Get your hands on the [Windows Media Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190307.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [libavcodec](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  See [audio_decode_example](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html#l00114) and [audio_encode_example](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html#l00046).  They use MP2 as an example, but both WMA and WAV (PCM) are [supported formats](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avcodec_8h.html#0c33394cb3458990f80b53c83ebe25f496c4248594701a622a77e70b26a91fe1).